# Classical regime for Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein gases

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm studying statistical mechanics, in particular classical regime for Fermi Dirac and Bose Einstein gases. Time average value for occupation numbers in FDBE statistics:
$$ \langle n_\epsilon\rangle_{FB} = \frac{1}{e^{(\epsilon-\mu)\beta}\pm1} $$
For Boltzmann Statistics:
$$ \langle n_\epsilon \rangle_B = e^{(\mu-\epsilon)\beta} $$
How can one work out a nice condition of classical regime in which $ \langle n_\epsilon\rangle_{FB} \rightarrow \langle n_\epsilon\rangle_B $ ?

An obvious option is $e^{\frac{(\epsilon-\mu)}{kT}}\gg1$. However, I don't really like it, since it implies convergence at low temperature. Moreover I'm expecting an $\epsilon$-free asymptotic expression in terms of temperature and density.

---

@Adam : i've read your comment again and things are much more clear now :)! 
Here's what i've got:

I'll assume $ \beta|\mu|>>1 $ and $\mu<0 $ or $z \rightarrow 0 $.

In terms of z:

$$ \langle n_\epsilon\rangle_{FB} = \frac{1}{\frac{e^{\epsilon\beta}}{z}\pm1} \, \,\underrightarrow{z\rightarrow0}  \, \,\langle n_\epsilon\rangle_{B}$$

Being $z=\lambda^3_t \rho$, i can say FDBE gases behaviour like classical one when the particle's thermal wavelenght is small if compared to the typical particle distance. Almost the "low density, high temperature" condition i was looking for.

At low temperature Boltzmann statistics lose physical mean (for example it's easy to recover the classical Sackur–Tetrode entropy from his thermodynamic) . Approximating in this scenary, although it may look mathematically legitimate,  is conceptually wrong. Quantum statistcs have to be handled carefully on their own.

Am i doing it right :)?

Sorry for the poor english.
Thanks you so much

Comment: On recover the classical regime in the limit $\mu<0$ and $|\mu|/T\gg 1$ (dilute gas).
See this question, and my answer there : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83173/what-is-the-relationship-between-maxwellboltzmann-statistics-and-the-grand-cano/87927#87927

Comment: sadly i still don't get it :(. maybe you have some link/reference about the subject?

Comment: Why do you expect an $\epsilon$-free asymptotic expression? I mean, you can express $\epsilon$ in terms of temperature and density, but to do so you absolutely need the partition function (I think).

Comment: @deppep: If you don't tell what you don't get, it will be hard to explain what's unclear... Tell me what you don't understand, and I will try to give more details.

Comment: @Adam , just edited the first post. take a look!

Comment: @deppep: Yes, that sounds good (though I don't know what $\rho$ is, and you should define $\lambda_t$).